# What is wrong with my autocommand groups?

Tags: autocmd, filetype

This is the current state of my autocmds.vim file.

```
" Option for specific filetypes                                                           
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.md    setlocal textwidth=80 spell spelllang=en_gb            
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.txt   setlocal textwidth=80 spell spelllang=en_gb            
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.tf    setlocal tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 expandtab              
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.json  setlocal tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 expandtab

" yaml
augroup filetype_yaml
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.{yaml,yml}
    autocmd FileType yaml |
        \ setlocal foldlevelstart=20 |
        \ setlocal foldmethod=indent |
        \ setlocal expandtab |
        \ setlocal shiftwidth=2 |
        \ setlocal softtabstop=2 |
        \ setlocal tabstop=2
augroup END

" sh
augroup filetype_sh
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.sh
    autocmd FileType sh |
        \ setlocal expandtab |
        \ setlocal shiftwidth=2 |
        \ setlocal softtabstop=2 |
        \ setlocal tabstop=2                                                              
augroup END
```

The problems are:

- The yaml and sh groups do not work. The settings do not apply when editing yaml or bash scripts.
- If any files that are opened I get this message when nvim starts, whether or not it's a shell file.

  --- Autocommands ---
  --- Autocommands ---
  filetypedetect  BufNewFile
  *.sh      call dist#ft#SetFileTypeSH(getline(1))
  Press ENTER or type command to continue

If I comment out the .sh group I still get the unwanted --- Autocommands --- message, but only once.

Comment: Consider putting local settings in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/sh.vim` (for example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for defining an autocmd is:

```
autocmd [event-list] [pattern] [commands]
```

Where [event-list] is a comma-separated list of events, the [pattern] is what to apply it to (what exactly it matches depends on the event(s), but it's often the filename), and [commands] is one or more commands; where multiple commands can be separated by a `|`.

The syntax for *viewing* which autocmds are defined is:

```
autocmd [event-list] [pattern]
```

Where [event-list] and [pattern] are optional (e.g. `autocmd` prints all autocommands, `autocmd Filetype` all filetype ones, `autocmd filetype sh` all sh filetype ones).

---

In your first, you have:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.{yaml,yml}
```

This is missing the [commands] part, so it's taken as a "view all autocommands for BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.{yaml,yml}". You can check this from the Vim commandline:

```
:autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.{yaml,yml}
--- Autocommands ---
```

No autocommands yet; let's define one:

```
:autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.{yaml,yml} echo 'a'
```

And now we can see it:

```
:autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.{yaml,yml}
--- Autocommands ---
BufNewFile
    *.{yaml,yml}
              echo 'a'
BufRead
    *.{yaml,yml}
              echo 'a'
```

One of the nice things about Vim is that anything you put in your vimrc can be entered as a command in the `:` commandline; it's a great way to figure things out.

Since you already have `autocmd FileType sh`, you can simply remove these for both the yaml and sh filetypes, as they're superfluous; Vim's built-in filetype detection should already set this for `*.sh`, `*.yml`, and `*.yaml` files.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your autocmd miss à command:

```
" yaml
augroup filetype_yaml
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.{yaml,yml} setlocal foldlevelstart=20 |
   \ setlocal foldmethod=indent |
   \ setlocal expandtab |
   \ setlocal shiftwidth=2 |
   \ setlocal softtabstop=2 |
   \ setlocal tabstop=2
augroup END
```